# Rails console wont open - no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, copycopter

I'm using Rails 3.2.11, Ruby 1.9.3, and cannot get rails console to open. No errors are being returned either. The only message I get is:

```
➜  projectname git:(development) ✗ rails c
** [Copycopter] [P:xxxx] [T:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Client 2.0.1 ready
** [Copycopter] [P:xxxx] [T:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.3] [Env: ]
** [Copycopter] [P:xxxx] [T:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Registered Resque after_perform hook
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure you cd into the project root directory and from there try `script/rails console`

Comment: yes, I made sure of this before posting. thank you for trying to help.

Comment: check your development log for output, also do you get different behavior if you `bundle exec rails console` instead? does rails server work ok? maybe an issue caused by copycopter ?

Comment: It sounds like his console is "starting" fine, as in there are no errors coming up its just that his terminal outputs the snippet he posted. I'm assuming that after you get those messages that your dumped into another command line prompt?

Comment: yes, `bundle exec rails c` adds an additional line:
`** [Copycopter] [P:xxxx] [T:xxxxxxxxxxxxx] Downloaded translations` --

`development.log` outputs the same for both `rails c` and `bundle exec` `rails c:
Connecting to database specified by database.yml`--

`rails s` works perfectly fine.

Comment: when removing copycopter from gemfile, running `rails c` only gives me a new line. I don't think it's a problem with copycopter.